# Energy change under point transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, differentiation

> How do the energy and generalized momenta change under the following
> coordinate
>
> transformation $$q= f(Q,t).$$

The new momenta: $$P = \partial L / \partial  \dot Q = \partial L / \partial \dot q\times \partial \dot q / \partial \dot Q = p  \partial \dot q / \partial \dot Q = p \partial q / \partial Q. $$

The new velocity:

$$\dot Q = \partial  Q / \partial q \times \dot q + \partial Q / \partial t.$$

The new energy:

$$E' = P\dot Q - L = p \partial q / \partial Q (\partial  Q / \partial q \times \dot q + \partial Q / \partial t) - L = p\dot q + p \partial q / \partial t - L = E + p \partial q / \partial t.$$

But the answer is
$$E' = E -  p \partial q / \partial t.$$

What did i got wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The [triple product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule):
$$ \left(\frac{\partial q}{\partial Q}\right)_t\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}\right)_q ~=~-\left(\frac{\partial q}{\partial t}\right)_Q.$$